# display DateTime format into readable string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have a stored DateTime with this format [2016-10-05 11:58:04]. What i want to do is, display the stored time into this readable format [Wed, 11:58 AM].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `mysqli` and `php` here are solutions for both:

### MySQL

You can format the date directly in your query:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(column_name, "%a, %h:%i %p") AS formatted_date FROM table_name
```

See docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

### PHP

If you have this string and need to format it in PHP, use `DateTime`:

```
$dt = new DateTime("2016-10-05 11:58:04");
echo $dt->format("D, h:i A"); // Wed, 11:58 AM
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/AQeTc

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
$dat = '2016-10-05 11:58:04';
$your_date = date("D, h:i A", strtotime($dat));
```

Where

```
D = day of the week
h = hour based on 2 x 12h day
i = minutes
A = AM or PM
```

function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

$date = '2016-10-05 11:58:04'

$human_readable_date = date('d-M-Y H:i:s', strtodate($date))

--output : 05-Oct-2016 11:58:04

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```
$date = "2016-10-05 11:58:04";
$newDateTime = date('D, h:i A', strtotime($date));
```